# How to interact with Azure IoT Edge Runtime from custom Edge Module running Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Our Edge Devices are based on the Azure IoT Edge Runtime. One of the modules, which is responsible of data processing is a custom module running a version of Apache Nifi. 
The output of the processing should either go to the Azure IoT Edge Message Bus and/or to the Cloud Upstream via IoT Hub.

Does anybody know how to connect those parts of the Edge System? 
Do we have to write C# code on the custom module to get this done or is there another way to accomplish this?

Edit:

After further investigation i learned that i can connect to IoT Hub using MQTT according to [this](http://busbyland.com/connect-mqtt-client-to-azure-iot-edge/) and interaction with the local Message Bus should be able by writing a custom Nifi Processor as shown [here](https://medium.com/hashmapinc/creating-custom-processors-and-controllers-in-apache-nifi-e14148740ea) using the [Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.device.moduleclient?view=azure-java-stable) SDK of the ModuleClient, just supplying a correct connection string and making sure, the custom container can reach the host machine via IP.

Do you think my assumptions are correct to achieve our goal?

Comment: in nifi there are [ConsumeMQTT](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-mqtt-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.mqtt.ConsumeMQTT/index.html) and [PublishMQTT](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-mqtt-nar/1.8.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.mqtt.PublishMQTT/index.html) processots. If your question about mqtt - then you don't need to write custom processor. if you need custom processor then you can use groovy script processor to minimize POC efforts.

Comment: @daggett Thank you for your comment. That would make interaction with the local IoT Hub even easier. Ok, so i could use the local IoT Hub via MQTT for Cloud Upstream and Module-To-Module communication?

Comment: Ok, i misunderstood IoT Edge Hub and the local message broker as being 2 different components but in fact they are the same. IoT Edge Hub takes care of both cloud upstream and local module-to-module communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct. You'll have to write a custom Nifi Processor using the Java Azure IoT SDK ModuleClient class. I've done something quite similar in my spring-boot-iotedge-sample of my Java Azure IoT Edge samples at https://github.com/JMayrbaeurl/azure-iotedge-java-samples